# Alinear Slider Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

La problemática es la siguiente:
tengo un Slider con 4 tarjetas el JavaScript se encarga de poner una en block y las otras en none si es que no hay evento en las dots o las arrow; ahora lo que quiero conseguir es que a cierta resolución esas tarjetas se hagan block para poder alinearlas las 4.
El problema es que consigo hacer bien ambas cosas, el slider a resolución menor de 992 se adapta bien, y si hago maniobras consigo  a 992 que se hagan block y queden acomodadas perfectamente como requiero, el detalle es que cuando consigo que las 4 estén acomodadas en resoluciones bajas mi  slider se desfasa.

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("target1");//toma cada div de la foto
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");// toma cada dot
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
   
 


}


function showElements(){
  const $body =  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
  console.log($body)
  let $target1 = document.getElementsByClassName('target1')
   for(let i = 0; i < $target1.length; i++){
      if($body == '992'){
        $target1[i].style.display='inline-block';
      }
   }
}

showElements()
```

```css
.container-slider{
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background:url("../IMG/fondoslider.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.container-slider .slider{

  background: #000;
     
   
}

.container-slider .target1{
    background: white;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    font-family: var(--fuente);
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    width: 79%;
    padding: var(--padding);
    margin:70px auto 0px auto;
  
  }


.testimonials{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-family: var(--fuente);
    
}

.container-slider a{
   
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

}



  .target-show{
      display: none;
  } 

.container-slider .circle{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid white;
    margin: -45px auto;
   background-color: #2f0ef1;
   color: white;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-family: var(--fuente);

}


  .container-slider .information{
      transform: translateY(50%)
  }
 

  .information .autor .span-autor{text-align: center; color: black;}
  
 
  .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 340px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;
    user-select: none;
  
   
  }
  
  .next {
    right: 11px;
    border-radius:50%;
  }
  
 .container-slider_dot{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin-bottom: 100px;

    }
  
.container-slider_dot .dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 20px 3px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }
  
  .active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
  }

  
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
  
  @keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
```

```html
 <div class="container-slider">
                   <div class="testimonials">
                      <h1>Success stories</h1>
                      <span><a href="">See More</a> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div class="target1  ">
                         <div class="circle">G</div>

                            <div class="information">
                                <p>A+ Experience.
                                    Very easy process from buying the domain to set it up...
                                    I highly recommend huge domains.”</p>
                                <span class="autor">g b web services,
                                <a class="span-autor" href="">DefiArt.com</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    


                        <div class="target1 ">
                            <div class="circle">T</div>
    
                            <div class="information">
                                <p>
                                    “Easy, breezy done! Very happy for the opportunity to obtain the domain.”</p>
                                    <span class="autor">Toni Moore,
                                    <a class="span-autor" href="">BawseLady.com</a>
                                </span>
                                </div>
    
                        </div>


                       <div class="target1 ">
                            <div class="circle">B</div>
    
                            <div class="information">
                                <p>
                                    “Easy, breezy done! Very happy for the opportunity to obtain the domain.”</p>
                                    <span class="autor">Brett Thomas,<br>
                                    <a class="span-autor" href="">RapidLeaderShip.com</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>


                      



                        <div class="target1  ">
                            <div class="circle">S</div>
    
                            <div class="information">
                                <p>“I have purchased more than a dozen premium domains from Huge Domains using their "payment plan" options.</p> 
                                    <span class="autor">Sergey Voronov,<br>
                                    <a class="span-autor" href="">GornItsa.com</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>


                        
                        
                        
                        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                                
                       
                        <div class="container-slider_dot" style="text-align:center">
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
                        
                        </div> 


                    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa imágen muestra como es que se desfasa cuando a 992 coloco los div en inlineBlock

Comment: Cuando la pantalla tiene el ancho deseado aplicas `display: inline-block;` a todos los elementos, pero deberías hacerlo solo con el que está activo. Además, es mejor crear [reglas en CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) que cambiar propiedades en Javascript. Igual para mostrar y ocultar, puedes hacerlo mediante clases de CSS.

Comment: De hecho tengo una regla a 992px pero no me deja hacer nada, así que lo hago con js porque es la única forma que logra hacer algo. Referente a lo que comentas de hacerlo solo con el activo ¿te refieres a cuando válido la resolución? la verdad ya estoy súper perdido .

Comment: Exacto, al validar la resolución es cuando a todos los elementos les cambias el atributo display y hace que se muestren todos al mismo tiempo, no solo el activo. Por otra parte, tanto en CSS como en Javascript va a ser muy difícil que obtengas esa medida exacta, probablemente deseas que sea menor o igual a 992. Luego, supongamos que la resolución coincide. Al avanzar el slider, en el evento asignas `display: block` y ya no funcionará lo que hiciste al cargar la página; por eso es que sugiero hacerlo solo con clases CSS y en Javascript solo las actualices.

Comment: Logré conseguirlo de esta manera: desde el css en resolución baja los puse en display none como me lo sugeriste, pero tuve algunos inconvenientes  así que seguí luchando y bueno en la función showslides en el for que los ponía en none los dejé vacío y así funciono,para serte bien sincero no entiendo el porque la verdad solo fue suerte, podrías porfavor decirme porque se comporta así?

Comment: Re subí el código para que veas y así no se si tu entiendas que pasó porque como te digo fue suerte no le entiendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te decía en comentarios, es mejor crear clases en CSS y, desde Javascript, solo agregar o eliminar las clases cuando sea necesario. Con *media queries* puedes cambiar el atributo deseado cuando el ancho de la pantalla sea igual a 992.

Revisa los comentarios para ver qué otros cambios se hicieron, tanto en Javascript como en CSS; al final se incluye la regla para ancho de pantalla y comentario por si deseas cambiar para que aplique en ancho igual o menor a 992px.

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("target1");//toma cada div de la foto
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");// toma cada dot
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      // Oculta eliminando la clase active
      slides[i].classList.remove('active');
      // Lo mismo para los puntos
      dots[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  // Activa el slide y el punto agregando la clase active
  slides[slideIndex-1].classList.add('active'); 
  dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add('active');
}

/* Esto no es necesario, lo haces con media queries de CSS *******
function showElements(){
  const $body =  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
  console.log($body)
  let $target1 = document.getElementsByClassName('target1')
   for(let i = 0; i < $target1.length; i++){
      if($body == '992'){
        $target1[i].style.display='inline-block';
      }
   }
}

showElements()
************ */
```

```css
.container-slider{
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background:url("../IMG/fondoslider.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.container-slider .slider{

  background: #000;
     
   
}

.container-slider .target1 {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    font-family: var(--fuente);
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    width: 79%;
    padding: var(--padding);
    margin:70px auto 0px auto;
    /* Todos ocultos por defecto */
    display:none;
}
/* Solo el que tenga la clase se va a mostrar */
.container-slider .target1.active {
    display:block;
}

.testimonials{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-family: var(--fuente);
    
}

.container-slider a{
   
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

}

  .target-show{
      display: none;
  } 

.container-slider .circle {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid white;
    margin: -45px auto;
   background-color: #2f0ef1;
   color: white;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-family: var(--fuente);

}


  .container-slider .information{
      transform: translateY(50%)
  }
 

  .information .autor .span-autor{text-align: center; color: black;}
  
 
  .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 340px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;
    user-select: none;
  
   
  }
  
  .next {
    right: 11px;
    border-radius:50%;
  }
  
 .container-slider_dot{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin-bottom: 100px;

    }
  
.container-slider_dot .dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 20px 3px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }

/* Usa todas las clases para que se apliquen las reglas */
.container-slider_dot .dot.active, .container-slider_dot .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}

  
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
  
  @keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
  
/* Mostrar como bloque en línea si la pantalla tiene ancho de 992px */
/* Si quieres que aplique a resoluciones menores cambia width por max-width */
@media screen and (width: 992px) {
    .container-slider .target1.active {
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-slider">
                   <div class="testimonials">
                      <h1>Success stories</h1>
                      <span><a href="">See More</a> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider">
                        <!-- Mostrar solo el primero al cargar la página, teniendo clase active -->
                        <div class="target1 active">
                         <div class="circle">G</div>

                            <div class="information">
                                <p>A+ Experience.
                                    Very easy process from buying the domain to set it up...
                                    I highly recommend huge domains.”</p>
                                <span class="autor">g b web services,
                                <a class="span-autor" href="">DefiArt.com</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    


                        <div class="target1 ">
                            <div class="circle">T</div>
    
                            <div class="information">
                                <p>
                                    “Easy, breezy done! Very happy for the opportunity to obtain the domain.”</p>
                                    <span class="autor">Toni Moore,
                                    <a class="span-autor" href="">BawseLady.com</a>
                                </span>
                                </div>
    
                        </div>


                       <div class="target1 ">
                            <div class="circle">B</div>
    
                            <div class="information">
                                <p>
                                    “Easy, breezy done! Very happy for the opportunity to obtain the domain.”</p>
                                    <span class="autor">Brett Thomas,<br>
                                    <a class="span-autor" href="">RapidLeaderShip.com</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>


                      



                        <div class="target1  ">
                            <div class="circle">S</div>
    
                            <div class="information">
                                <p>“I have purchased more than a dozen premium domains from Huge Domains using their "payment plan" options.</p> 
                                    <span class="autor">Sergey Voronov,<br>
                                    <a class="span-autor" href="">GornItsa.com</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>


                        
                        
                        
                        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                                
                       
                        <div class="container-slider_dot" style="text-align:center">
                        <span class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
                        
                        </div> 


                    </div>
```